# Can I measure distances with sound in an android app?

Tags: android, waveform, audio-processing

I've got a number of questions this time, although they all relate to the same problem: I wanted to build a rudimentary sonar in Android, and have no clue as to how possible it is to do such a thing.

- Is it something that can work reasonably well?
- What's the best way (that makes sense in a mobile app) to compare waveforms?
- Can I even reliably measure the delay between sending and receiving a given waveform in a small-ish enclosure(say, a room)?
- Is there any way (that makes sense in a mobile app) to discard noise created by, for instance, uneven surfaces (say, with open doors)?

Just trying to get oriented here, as I'm *really* new to sound processing in mobile apps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4uSRCKC6Wo) ?

Comment: I have same problem, did you solve it?